# How to select an element which doesn't have a specific class name, using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, class, jquery-selectors, sizzle

How could a Commando, like myself, select an element witch does not have a class named "active", using the infamous and powerful jQuery Sizzle CSS and everything else - Selector?

I've tried with:

```
$('a[class!="active"]').etc();
```

But it gives no adequate results.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('a:not(.active)')
```

should work

---

yours works as well. just tested:
http://jsfiddle.net/UP6a7/

Comment: this works with $('#parent').find('a:not(.active)'); as well?

Comment: @Andy: _"yours works as well"_, [for single classed elements](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/EYUQu/).

Comment: @Commando: Yes, it works even with that! Or directly `$('#parent a:not(.active)');`

Comment: @Shef: right, this could work though :) $('a:not([class*="active"])')

Comment: @Andy: Yeah, but it's still Sizzle, so not much improvement with that. :)

Comment: @Shef: just a slightly different approach, closer to his original code :)

Comment: @Andy: Shef is right. Class name, in my case, might be: "class anotherClass andAnotherClassAsWell" :)